# Unable to print correct custom property value using delegated properties approach for an environment variable in Gradle Kotlin DSL

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

Original issue: https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/14253

Currently (as stated in the github issue), I'm unable to get the custom property via delegated property (`by property`)

Consider this starter snippet code:

```
// app/build.gradle.kts
val foo: String? by project
val outputEnvirontmentVariable by tasks.registering(Task::class) {
    println("my foo: $foo")
}
```

#### Expected Behavior

In the Current Behavior section should be print `bar` as well when configuring the environment variable

#### Current Behavior

When running this task:

```
(root-directory)$: gradle outputEnvirontmentVariable
```

Below are the result for both approach (system property vs. environment variable):

Setting a project property via an environment variable: `ORG_GRADLE_PROJECT_foo=bar`

```
// env variable inside bash/zsh profile file
ORG_GRADLE_PROJECT_foo=bar
```

Result:

```
my foo: null
```

Setting a project property via a system property: `org.gradle.project.foo=bar`

Result:

```
my foo: bar
```

#### Context

Either I've missing something or my implementation incorrect, please cmiiw~

Answer (score 0):

I'm closing the issue on github due to incorrect implementation. See below for the correct ways to call `org.gradle.project` or `ORG_GRADLE_PROJECT` to be treated as Project Property:

- The `system property` approach need to have a prefix `systemProp.` before `org.gradle.project.<your-key>`

```
// gradle.properties
systemProp.org.gradle.project.foo="<your-value>"
```

- Or for `environment variable` approach I'm forgot using `export`, without it the key-value not treated as correct environment variable

```
// bash/zsh profile
export ORG_GRADLE_PROJECT_foo="<your-value>"
```

Just call `val foo: String? by project` for nullable or `val foo: String by project` for non-null in your `build.gradle.kts`